# Using MSAL with non-Microsoft Identity providers

Tags: identity, azure-ad-msal, idp

I would like to know if MSAL can be used with Identity providers other than Microsoft products. If yes, how.
I checked the MSAL documentetion but it is not straightforward in this question.
What I would like to do is to authenticate to Google and OneLogin (and possibly others later) using MSAL, but I don't know how.
However, I successfully used MSAL with Azure AD.

MSAL seems to be a good library to use it generally with any IDPs.

Comment: I'm struggling with the documentation too, its really really poor. I'm thinking of sticking with AddMicrosoftAccount for now

Comment: Did you happen to get a solution to this problem? I would expect an OIDC compliant client to work with any OIDC based IDP. But looking at he source of MSAL (even 4.37), I don't think it is easy to use as a generic client.

Comment: @KTib, did you find the answer? I'm trying to figure out if we can use MSAL for both Azure (I know we can) and custom OAUTH2-compliant identity providers and the documentation is still murky.

Answer (score 2):

**PROVISO**

I believe you're asking about [MSAL.JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js), as using [MSAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki#conceptual-documentation) with a non-MS OpenID Connect provider is unnecessary, as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` provides sufficient [support for social logins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/) and vendors of custom OpenID Connect servers provide own extensions (see [IdentityServer docs](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/fundamentals/clients/) and [OpenIdDict samples](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples))

**ANSWER**

Yes, it's possible to use a non-MS OIDC provider with MSAL.JS since October 2020.

You'd have to specify extra `auth` properties: `protocolMode: 'OIDC'` and `knownAuthorities: ["your-id-server.com"]`. See [the official docs](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/configuration.md) on the parameters of `@azure/msal-browser`.

If you follow [the official JavaScript examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react) then the config would look like:

```
auth: {
    clientId: "YOUR-CLIENT-ID",
    authority: "https://your-id-server.com",
    knownAuthorities: ["https://your-id-server.com"],
    redirectUri: "https://you-client-app.com",
    protocolMode: "OIDC"
}
```

**HISTORY**

Till [this PR](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/2389) was merged 16-Oct-2020, [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) worked with MS end-points exclusively. So the @leastprivilege's answer of 2017 was correct back then.

Thankfully, issue requests [1555](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1555) and subsequently [2120](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2120) helped to change the tide.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. Can we use MSAL for Client Credentials-based authentication flows against non-Azure identity providers (that support OAUTH2)? Looking for a common solution for a server-to-server app that talks to both Azure and non-Azure systems.

Comment: The OPs question and my answer are about using MSAL with non-MS OpenID Connect Identity Providers.
I think you're using incorrect terminology in your question. There's OAuth 2.0 [Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4), but  "_Client Credentials-based flows_" is not a thing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [reply from the MSAL.NET GitHub discussion](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/discussions/3708), MSAL.NET only supports Azure identity providers, so as of September of 2022, it would not work with third-party providers. The third-party support may be added later, but no timeline at this point.